# Should avoid to pass component type by props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I am coding, I feel implementing as the following is the most convenient, even I know `render props` also can do it.

```
const Parent = ({Child1:ComponentTyp<Props1>,Child2:ComponentTyp<Props2>})=>{
     const someProps1:Prop1 = {...};
     const someProps2:Prop2 = {...};

     return (<>
               <Child1 ...someProps1/>
               <SomeOtherComponent></SomeOtherComponent>
               <Child2 ...someProps/>
            </>)
}

const Componenet1 = ()=><Parent Child1={Componenet1_Child1} Child2={Componenet2_Child2} />;
const Componenet2 = ()=><Parent Child1={Componenet2_Child1} Child2={Componenet2_Child2} />;
`Componenet1_Child1` and `Componenet2_Child1` have the same props(Props1).
`Componenet1_Child2` and `Componenet2_Child2` have the same props(Props2).
```

But it seems to be not good.
Should I avoid implementing as the above, why?

I could not find the real reason except elegance。

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It seems fine to me. However, pass only props that Child Component needs will make your code clear and easy to debug

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your types. Do you mean `Child1:ComponentType`?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is in a sense "render props".
The benefit I can think of for your approach over vanilla "render props" is that you can safely use hooks in the functions you pass in as props.

One thing to consider as downside for your approach, (but it applies to "render props" as well), is that it is harder to understand than simple composition, so unless `someProps` depend on the state of `Parent` it's better to have them as actual children.

```
const Parent: React.FunctionComponent<{ children: [React.ReactElement, React.ReactElement] }> = (props) => { 
    return <>
        {props.children[0]}
        <SomeOtherComponent/>
        {props.children[1]}
    </>
}
```

Play with the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gGVckB5GACySgGFdIqkq8ALxwAFAEo4QgHxwqAVwA2i8pVrwACiiKCAXImIwAdADF5VDMGo9w1ATAA8Abzho2wRQBMd%20gNrJ0YwCMAFFFJBB7ABoDQKNgmDCI%20wBdOABfWRFRMBwwGkkZOBdSODK4Ihh5KCo4B2lS8qanXIh8ozcPbwFfAAYU9MamsodGSNYObl47QQB6BuHylryaDvcvHV8ARgGhuvnSQdJMc0tqColivcrq2octHRgFxbqxlnZOGz57OAOX16YE0%20034gl%20zxGswe9mkAG5DkA).

Another topic you might consider reading on is [higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).